# How to add google native ads between listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view where I add items from server (database) I want to add native ad between this listview please help

I used fundapter to add items in listview like this---

**Code**

```
    {    
HashMap postData = new HashMap();
PostResponseAsyncTask taskInsert = new PostResponseAsyncTask(slider2.this,
    postData, new AsyncResponse() {                
    @Override
    public void processFinish(String s) {
        productList = new JsonConverter<product_main_list>().toArrayList(s, product_main_list.class);
        dict = new BindDictionary<>();
        dict.addStringField(R.id.t1, new StringExtractor<product_main_list>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(product_main_list product, int position) {
               // Toast.makeText(slider2.this, "name  "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return product.name;
            }
        });

        dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.im1, new StringExtractor<product_main_list>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(product_main_list product, int position) {
               // Toast.makeText(slider2.this, "im  "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String link = "<link>";
                return link;
            }
        }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
            @Override
            public void loadImage(String url, ImageView view) {
                Picasso.with(slider2.this)
                        .load(url)
                        // .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        // .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .resize(300, 300)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(view);
            }
        });
      //  Toast.makeText(slider2.this, "s", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter = new FunDapter<>(slider2.this, productList, R.layout.activity_main, dict);
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
taskInsert.execute("<link of php file in server>");
}
```

Comment: You can define ad layout as raw item layout! and make it `visible` and `invisible`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add native ads in a listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340440/how-to-add-native-ads-in-a-listview)